# Multidimensional integral of exponential of variable

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, density-function, exponential-distribution

I'm interesting in finding the exponential family density associated with the function $$p_\theta(x) = \exp(\theta^T x - A(\theta)) \text{ with } x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+.$$

In this case, I have $\log A(\theta) = \int \exp(\theta^T x)\,dx$ where the integral is over the domain of $x$ (since $-\log A(\theta)$ is a normalizing function for the density)

I am trying to evaluate the integral to determine which exponential family is associated with the distribution. My exploration here took me to Gaussian integrals, namely trying to use the real multidimensional Gaussian integral (from [here](http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/gonsalves/aqm/lectures/20/lec-20.pdf)) but this doesn't work since the determinant in the resulting function is zero (and thus the integral would be zero). Is it possible to find a closed form solution to this multivariable integral?

Am I even going down the wrong route by trying to evaluate the integral at all? Based on the non-normalized probability, this appears to represent the join distribution of independent exponential random variables, but that is merely a hunch.

Comment: The whole point of writing $\exp x$ instead of $e^x$ is to avoid the superscript when you have $\exp(\bullet)$ where $\bullet$ is a long and complicated expression.  One doesn't write $\exp^x$, with a superscript.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: It might be easier to address your question if you told us what the singular matrix is and how it fits into this. $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry about the subscript on $\exp$. That was a mistake and I totally understand the difference. Anyway, I simply looked at Gaussian integrals to try to figure out how to integrate $\exp \theta x$. I tried to create an integral in Gaussian form such that the matrix $P$ associated with the quadratic form was all zeros, so the only remaining part of the integral would be the affine function composed within the exponential. This doesn't work because the Gaussian integral result has a product with $\det P$ in the answer.

Comment: Just for clarity, the $A(\theta)$ in the post isn't a matrix, but some function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Only adding this clarification as the matrix associated with the quadratic form in the document I linked is also denoted as $A$.

Comment: So you have
$$
A(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n) = \int_{[0,\infty]^n} e^{\theta_1 x_1+\cdots+\theta_n x_n} \, d(x_1,\ldots,x_n).
$$
And you're saying something doesn't work because the determinant of some matrix is $0$.  Which matrix? $\qquad$

Comment: Actually, the above integral is $\log A$. The overall problem I'm trying to solve is determining which the exponential family of densities associated with my function. My primary issue is that I do not know how to integrate the above expression.  I thought that my integral might be a specific parametrization of the formula on page two of the included link. I was simply trying to provide some context for how I'd tried to solve the problem. However, I do not believe it is applicable, but I thought I'd include it in case I'd simply made a mistake.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. The matrix that I've been referring to isn't as directly related to the problem as I may have made in seem in the original post. I was only including it for context -- it is the matrix in the more general integral $\int e^{x^T P x + K^T x + b} dx$ -- of which a specific closed form indefinite integral is provided in the attached link. In my problem, it is all zeros, so I believe $\det P = 0$